# Is the CMB Cold spot growing or shrinking?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

What do we know about the nature of this region of the sky? is that region entirely devoid of galaxies?

Could it be a bubble void, and we are simply unable to see the galaxies that are on the opposite side of the bubble?

Comment: what is a "bubble void"? The CMB is a snapshot of what was happening at 380.000 years after the BB. we are at 14billion+ as far as cosmological modeling goes.

Comment: Note that the CMB has nothing to do with whether or not we can see galaxies in that particular direction: in fact, there were no galaxies for long after the CMB that we see was emitted.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to know, and specifically what isn't [already covered by the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMB_cold_spot).